# MS Word - How to disable the OneDrive handling

Tags: microsoft-word, macbook, onedrive

When click OPEN, it show 2 locations: ONEDRIVE and LOCAL.
I don't want to show ONEDRIVE option, how to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Office for Windows which could use registry keys to block OneDrive, to remove OneDrive as a storage location on Office for Mac, you need to **sign out** your Microsoft account.

Maybe you could try it as a workaround, so that Office is not connected to the cloud service which is associated with your account, such as the OneDrive.